# Convert promise to observable Keycloak

Tags: angular, rxjs, keycloak

I have keycloak methods, it's tedious for me to redo them, I don't understand a little

```
export class AuthGuard extends KeycloakAuthGuard {
  constructor(
    protected readonly router: Router,
    protected readonly keycloak: KeycloakService
  ) {
    super(router, keycloak);
  }

  public isAccessAllowed(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<boolean> {
    if (!this.authenticated) {
       this.keycloak.login({
        redirectUri: window.location.origin + state.url,
      });
    }
    const requiredRoles = route.data.roles;
    if (!(requiredRoles instanceof Array) || requiredRoles.length === 0) {
      return true;
    }
    return requiredRoles.every((role) => this.roles.includes(role));
  }
}
```

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

not sure what You want to do exactly but if keycloak method returns promise You can just use use `fromPromise` and return

```
  if (!this.authenticated) {
       return fromPromise(this.keycloak.login({
        redirectUri: window.location.origin + state.url,
      }));
    }
```

```
    if (!(requiredRoles instanceof Array) || requiredRoles.length === 0) {
      return of(true);
    }
```

and

```
return of(requiredRoles.every((role) => this.roles.includes(role));)
```